# mvc4 bool becomes a rectange instead of true and false

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i have a model contains a bool value,

when i present that value in the view i got this image

[image]

#### how to make it just `True` or `False`

Comment: That, by the way, is the default way they are supposed to render; as an `<input type="checkbox">`, so that users can check/uncheck them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on how you present the data (mark up) in your view.

`@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.BoolValue)` -> renders a checkbox so that the user can "edit" the data.

`@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.BoolValue)` -> renders the string "BoolValue" unless you have a data annotation (`[DisplayName("Some New Name")]`) naming it something different.  This is to generate a label to associate with a checkbox.

`@model.BoolValue` -> Will render true or false, whatever the value of the BoolValue variable is.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `Html.EditorFor`, you simply want to use `@Model.IsFurnished`.

`Html.EditorFor` will provide a checkbox for a `bool` because it is the most logical way to represent a value of `true` or `false`.